# R foreach stop iteration at i

Tags: r, parallel-foreach

I am using R package `foreach`. 
When bug exists in `foreach` block, it's hard to re-occur it and hard to debug.

Take the following script as example.
I want to stop at `i=4` to check what's wrong. However, it stops at `i=10`.

Any solution?

```r
library(foreach)
foreach(i = icount(10)) %do% {
    if (i == 4){
        e <- simpleError("test error")
        stop(e)
    }
}
```

Comment: Eventually you want use `break` ... (documentation of `for (...)`)

Comment: `for (...)` is not suit. Because `foreach` can be easily modified into parallel mode. modifying `foreach` into `for` every time when debugging, is a little tired.

Answer (score 1):

One option to handle this is with a `browser()` inside a `tryCatch` as in:

```
foreach(i = icount(10)) %do% {
  tryCatch(
    if (i == 4){
      e <- simpleError("test error")
      stop(e)
    },
    error = function(e) browser()
  )
}
```

This will produce a browser of the environment at the time of the error, which will allow you to inspect any objects and/or debug your code.

Your console will then look like the following and you can ask what the value of i is.  Like this:

Browse[1]> i

[1] 4